# Google Chrome Resources: Cache Storage

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools

Google has documented the devtools of chrome here. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/resource-panel

However, there is one feature called "Cache Storage", but the document does not refer to it.

[image: Google Chrome Devtools]

Does anyone have any idea what Cache Storage does?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, straight from 'google developers twitter account'

"it is the Cache Object that was introduced in Service Worker (and now on window)"

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/updates-to-cache-api?hl=en